# Find the sum of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}$ and specify if it is convergent or divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I have to find the sum of the following series and specify if it is convergent or divergent:

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}$$

This is what I have so far:

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}
= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{5 \cdot 2^{3n}}{5^{n}}
= \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{5 \cdot (2^{3})^{n}}{5^{n}}
= 5 \cdot \sum_{n \ge 0} \bigg (\frac{8}{5} \bigg )^n$$

From here I said that:

$$\frac{8}{5} > 1 \Rightarrow \bigg (\frac{8}{5} \bigg) ^ {n} \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

And because of this I concluded that the sum of the series is $\infty$, thus the series is divergent. However, I am not very satisfied with this last part. It doesn't feel right to jump from

$$\bigg (\frac{8}{5} \bigg) ^ {n} \rightarrow \infty \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

to

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}} = \infty$$

What extra steps am I missing?

Comment: Your argument is sufficient. Alternatively you may argue $\left(\frac85\right)^n > 1$, or employ the ratio test.

Comment: You are using the counterpart of "If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$". It absolutely correct.

Comment: You may feel better if you think about your argument this way: because $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, then $a_n > 1$ for all $n$ sufficiently large (say $n \ge N$), implying that $\sum_{n = 1}^{N + m} a_n \ge \sum_{n = N}^{N + m} a_n > m$, which $\to \infty$ as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: The part you are unsatisfied with is strange because I bet it is obvious to you that adding infinitely many $1$'s diverges. This is greater than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is divergent and can be proven with the quotient test, assuming
$ a_n = \frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}} $ and showing that $ \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n } = \frac{8}{5}> 1$ and therefore the series does not converge

Comment: It converges in the field $\Bbb Q_2$ of $2$-adic numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is fine, as an alternative

$$\frac{2^{3n}}{5^{n-1}} =\frac{8^n}{5^{n-1}}\ge \frac{8^n}{8^{n-1}}=8$$

and therefore the series diverges.